# Trouble adding Hadoop node in Datastax Enterprise

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

I'm having a difficult time adding a hadoop node in datastax enterprise 4.5.1. I have an existing Cassandra virtual dc with two nodes, using vnodes. I am using opscenter, and I startup a hadoop node, setting the initial_token value to 0. Opscenter installs everything just fine (i.e. I get passed the 5 green dots), but about a minute after, the node dies. The system.log file has this exception:

```
 INFO [main] 2014-12-28 05:40:37,931 StorageService.java (line 1007) JOINING: Starting to bootstrap...
ERROR [main] 2014-12-28 05:40:37,998 CassandraDaemon.java (line 513) Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No sources found for (-1,0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getAllRangesWithSourcesFor(RangeStreamer.java:159)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:117)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:72)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1035)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:797)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:614)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:504)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:378)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:394)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.main(DseDaemon.java:574)
 INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2014-12-28 05:40:38,015 Gossiper.java (line 1279) Announcing shutdown
 INFO [Thread-1] 2014-12-28 05:40:38,015 DseDaemon.java (line 477) DSE shutting down...
 INFO [Thread-1] 2014-12-28 05:40:38,022 PluginManager.java (line 317) All plugins are stopped.
 INFO [Thread-1] 2014-12-28 05:40:38,023 CassandraDaemon.java (line 463) Cassandra shutting down...
ERROR [Thread-1] 2014-12-28 05:40:38,023 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.stop(CassandraDaemon.java:464)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.stop(DseDaemon.java:480)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon$1.run(DseDaemon.java:384)
 INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2014-12-28 05:40:40,015 MessagingService.java (line 683) Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
 INFO [ACCEPT-/172.31.19.81] 2014-12-28 05:40:40,017 MessagingService.java (line 923) MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
```

I have a keyspace that looks like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'Analytics': '1',
  'Cassandra': '1'
};
```

I'm wondering if it is because I am using vnodes in my Cassandra dc and not in the Analytics dc? The datastax documentation mentions this type of mixed architecture is ok. My snitch is set to DSEDelegateSnitch, which in turn uses DSESimpleSnitch, the default. I've ran a node repair, but to no avail. One other detail is that in opscenter, I get a warning that I am using two different versions of a Datastax enterprise, 4.5.1 in my cassandra dc, and 2.0.8.39 in the Analytics dc. In addition, opscenter lists the hadoop dc as "unknown." Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: I can add a solr node just fine.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason why you are using Hadoop rather than Spark?

Comment: I just tried the same sequence using 4 Amazon EC2 nodes and it worked fine (install OpsCenter onto node 1, use OpsCenter to create Cassandra cluster on nodes 2 & 3, then add Hadoop node 4). The vnode mixture should be fine (Analytics with vnodes off), and the snitch is fine. Can you share more details about your environment? I suspect the new Hadoop node is not able to connect back to the cluster during bootstrapping, and closing down as a result.